# Why bother creating the first dataset when using table component?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've been trying to use Jasper Reports Studio 6.2 and am struggling to understand the Datasets.

I don't understand why I'm asked to create a dataset when I create a new report, then asked to create another new dataset when I add a 'table' object. I don't get the first one... in my mind, the one that's associated with the creation of the 'table' object would have the SQL query, and be the data object. If that's the case, what was the point of creating one at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The data-source for the **report** will iterate on the reports **detail band**
>
> The data-source for the **table** will iterate the **rows** on your table.

If you have only a table in the report you can

- Pass an [JREmptyDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JREmptyDataSource.html) example `new JREmptyDataSource(1)`, this will show detail band once

or

- Put the table in for example the `summary` band and set the attribute `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` on the `jasperReport` tag and then pass no datasource to the fill manager.

Why can both be useful?, the first you use to show data using the normal `detail` band and the second one you use to show for example a table that sums up data on the `summary` band

Comment: So If I'm making a simple report that uses SQL to an Oracle Database, should I be using one way vs. another? I thought the table made the most sense, but maybe I should be creating the layout manually with column headers, and then my data fields in the detail band?

Comment: My suggestion if you are beginning to use jasper do not use tables... using the detail band give you much more options as grouping ecc.., table is actually a component of latest version of jasper report (before you did table using subreport), so consider the table as a subreport type.